# Pivot the table along with sum total

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with these data

```
+------------+----------------+------------+
| Department | ProgressStatus | TasksCount |
+------------+----------------+------------+
| A          | Completed      |          1 |
| C          | Completed      |          4 |
| D          | Completed      |          1 |
| B          | Pending        |          8 |
| A          | Pending        |         10 |
| C          | Pending        |         12 |
| D          | Pending        |          2 |
| C          | Progress       |          4 |
+------------+----------------+------------+
```

I need to write a query to get these outputs (It looks like a simple pivot table).

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Departments | Completed | Pending | Progress | Total Tasks  |
+-------------+-----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| A           |         1 |      10 |        0 |           11 |
| B           |         0 |       8 |          |            8 |
| C           |         4 |      12 |        4 |           20 |
| D           |         1 |       2 |          |            3 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Actully i'm new to SQL. so all what i could do is geting the totsl tasks for each department, but i couldn't get the rest :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using conditional SUM and GROUP BY

```
select
    department,
    sum(case when ProgressStatus = 'Completed' then TasksCount end) Completed,
    sum(case when ProgressStatus = 'Pending' then TasksCount end) Pending,
    sum(case when ProgressStatus = 'Progress' then TasksCount end) Progress,
    sum(TasksCount) Total
from your_table
group by department;
```

Comment: It worked :) thanks. Could you please tell me about good resource where i can learn SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
BY using pivot i tried like this 

SELECT  Department,isnull(Completed,0) Completed,isnull([Pending],0) [Pending],isnull([Progress],0) [Progress]
          ,isnull(Completed,0)+isnull([Pending],0)+isnull([Progress],0) as 'total'
    FROM #Table2
    PIVOT ( sum([TasksCount])
      for [ProgressStatus] in ([Completed], [Pending], [Progress])) AS pvt
```

output

```
Department  Completed   Pending Progress    total
A                1       10       0          11
B                0       8        0           8
C                4      12        4          20
D                1      2         0           3
```

Comment: it works also. but i can not understand it for now :(. Thank you for your help

Comment: just see examples of pivot you can u understand what is happening...@EmadAli